# Adding 'OldValue' property to Dapper.Snapshotter.Changes object

Tags: c#, cil

We use Dapper's Snapshotter extensively so identify property changes to make updates more efficient.  We're now looking to use it to identify changes that could be used for logging.  In order to do this, we need to add the property `OldValue` to the nested class `Changes` (which has `Name` and `NewValue`).

All the information is there in this class, but it uses the Emit library.  I've tried various line additions trying to access that original property's value and set it to `OldValue`:

e.g.
`il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(Change).GetMethod("set_OldValue"));`

However, I keep getting errors saying that it destabilizes the runtime.  I like to tinker, but the Emit library is very new ground.  I was hoping someone (...https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell...https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) with expertise could guide me here.

```
     private static Func<T, T, List<Change>> GenerateDiffer()
                    {

                        var dm = new DynamicMethod("DoDiff", typeof(List<Change>), new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(T) }, true);

                        var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
                        // change list
                        il.DeclareLocal(typeof(List<Change>));
                        il.DeclareLocal(typeof(Change));
                        il.DeclareLocal(typeof(object)); // boxed change

                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(List<Change>).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
                        // [list]
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);

                        foreach (var prop in RelevantProperties())
                        {
                            // []
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                            // [original]
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, prop.GetGetMethod(true));
                            // [original prop val]
/*****
MAYBE SET ORIGINAL PROP VAL HERE?
*****/


                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
                            // [original prop val, current]
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, prop.GetGetMethod(true));
                            // [original prop val, current prop val]

                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
                            // [original prop val, current prop val, current prop val]

                            if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(string))
                            {
                                il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, prop.PropertyType);
                                // [original prop val, current prop val, current prop val boxed]
                            }

                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_2);
                            // [original prop val, current prop val]

                            il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Snapshot<T>).GetMethod("AreEqual", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { prop.PropertyType }), null);
                            // [result] 

                            Label skip = il.DefineLabel();
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, skip);
                            // []

                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(Change).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
                            // [change]
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
                            // [change,change]

                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);
                            // [change]

                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, prop.Name);
                            // [change, name]
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(Change).GetMethod("set_Name"));
                            // []

                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
                            // [change]

                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_2);
                            // [change, boxed]

                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(Change).GetMethod("set_NewValue"));
                            // []

                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                            // [change list]
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
                            // [change list, change]
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(List<Change>).GetMethod("Add"));
                            // []

                            il.MarkLabel(skip);
                        }

                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                        // [change list]
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                        return (Func<T, T, List<Change>>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, T, List<Change>>));
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This does it!  After adding the OldValue to Changes, Basically, declare a new local variable and push retrieve the value and pop it into that local var.

```
private static Func<T, T, List<Change>> GenerateDiffer()
                {
    
                    var dm = new DynamicMethod("DoDiff", typeof(List<Change>), new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(T) }, true);
    
                    var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
                    // change list
                    il.DeclareLocal(typeof(List<Change>));
                    il.DeclareLocal(typeof(Change));
                    il.DeclareLocal(typeof(object)); // boxed new value
                    il.DeclareLocal(typeof(object)); // RM - boxed old value
    
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(List<Change>).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
                    // [list]
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
    
                    foreach (var prop in RelevantProperties())
                    {
                        
    
    
    
    
    
                        //[]
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                         //[original]
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, prop.GetGetMethod(true));
                        //[original prop val]
    
    
                        /*
                         * We're going to dupe and store the old value into loc3.
                         */
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
                        // [original prop val, current prop val, current prop val]
    
                        if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(string))
                        {
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, prop.PropertyType);
                            // [original prop val, current prop val, current prop val boxed]
                        }
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_3);
                        // [original prop val, current prop val]
    
                        /*
                         * 
                         */
    
    
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
                        // [original prop val, current]
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, prop.GetGetMethod(true));
                        // [original prop val, current prop val]
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
                        // [original prop val, current prop val, current prop val]
    
                        if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(string))
                        {
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, prop.PropertyType);
                            // [original prop val, current prop val, current prop val boxed]
                        }
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_2);
                        // [original prop val, current prop val]
    
    
                        il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Snapshot<T>).GetMethod("AreEqual", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { prop.PropertyType }), null);
                        // [result] 
    
                       
                        Label skip = il.DefineLabel();
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, skip);
                        // []
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(Change).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
                        // [change]
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
                        // [change,change]
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);
                        // [change]
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, prop.Name);
                        // [change, name]
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(Change).GetMethod("set_Name"));
                        // []
    
                        /*
                         * Begin setting value
                         */
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
                        // [change]
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_3);
                        // [change, boxed]
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(Change).GetMethod("set_OldValue"));
                        // []
    
                        /*
                         * End Playground
                         */
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
                        // [change]
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_2);
                        // [change, boxed]
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(Change).GetMethod("set_NewValue"));
                        // []
    
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                        // [change list]
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
                        // [change list, change]
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(List<Change>).GetMethod("Add"));
                        // []
    
                        il.MarkLabel(skip);
                    }
    
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                    // [change list]
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    
                    return (Func<T, T, List<Change>>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, T, List<Change>>));
                }
```